# Can I use the worker MPM with mod_php?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, centos6

After reading [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/383634/184461), I decided to change httpd's MPM on my server to worker. But while editing `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`, I noticed this comment:

```
# The default processing model (MPM) is the process-based
# 'prefork' model.  A thread-based model, 'worker', is also
# available, but does not work with some modules (such as PHP).
# The service must be stopped before changing this variable.
#
#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
```

I may be interpreting it wrong, but isn't it telling me that worker will **not** work with mod_php? Because that is what I am currently using.

The server runs CentOS 6.4 and Apache 2.2.

Comment: You can't use mod_php with worker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No - you can't - you'll have mysterious bugs and crashes as PHP isn't thread-safe.

But you can use worker-mpm for static files and something like `php_fcgi` or a reverse proxy to another httpd instance only for PHP.

I'm using the latter - it allows me to run multiple sites - all with different permissions and configs on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, mod_php is not thread-safe.