# How do you tell Apache 2.4 which MPM to use on Amazon Linux?

Tags: apache-2.4, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker

[How do I select which Apache MPM to use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use) talks about the pros and cons of the different MPMs. This question is: How does one tell Apache 2.4 which MPM to use?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf` which looks like:

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```