# best configuration for 5k requests per second apache

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, cache, performance-tuning

I have a webserver which has 5k requests per second
this overloads my server with the cpu usage

host has 12 CPU and 8GB ram [ almost not in use ]

my httpd-mpm configuration is below :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit         1000
    MaxRequestWorkers   8000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    ThreadsPerChild         32
    MaxRequestWorkers      8000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             6
    MinSpareThreads         32
    MaxSpareThreads        128
    ThreadsPerChild         64
    ServerLimit             32
    MaxRequestWorkers     2048
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum  number of connections a thread serves. It
#                         is recommended that the default value of 0 be set
#                         for this directive on NetWare.  This will allow the
#                         thread to continue to service requests indefinitely.
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          5
    MaxSpareThreads         10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# The maximum number of free Kbytes that every allocator is allowed
# to hold without calling free(). In threaded MPMs, every thread has its own
# allocator. When not set, or when set to zero, the threshold will be set to
# unlimited.
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree            2048
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>
```

and the server is still overloaded

do you have any suggetions? what to check? maybe change any configuration?

thank you!

Comment: Most distributions load the prefork MPM by default and for performance you may want to [select a different MPM](https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use) or do like many high performance websites and move away from apache httpd completely and switch for instance to nginx. - Also: https://serverfault.com/q/350454/37681