# Apache HTTPD MPM Worker or Event for Reverse Proxy with SSL Termination

Tags: ssl, proxy, httpd

I'm running reverse proxies with httpd 2.4.27 on RHEL 6 for various organizational reasons. The reverse proxies have to terminate SSL/TLS instead of the load balancer, which makes me want to consider how mpm_event handles SSL connections.

I've read several places that mpm_event may fall back to mpm_worker when handling SSL connections. I cannot find a definitive answer if that's still the case in my version. Is that still how it works?

Comment: Do you have an example of where you read that? It sounds a little unbelievable.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use

Comment: That's the first place I saw it mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `mpm_event` can fall back to synchronous reads similar to what `mpm_worker` does when input filters are clogged, not the `mpm_worker` module itself (MPM modules don't change at runtime). `mod_ssl` is mentioned as one possible source of this clogging of input filters.

I haven't experienced any issues due to this handling myself, so I can't comment whether this is a bad thing or not.

You can find the relevant code [here in the Apache HTTPd source code repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/server/mpm/event/event.c?view=markup#l1035).