# apache's processes number growing

Tags: apache-2.4

My apache2, running on a debian stretch server, often shows instabilities that make the apache's processes number grow, as in this image:

[image: Apache processes munin graphs]

When the processes number reaches the maximum processes number allowed, the apache server reaches a saturation point and stops responding.

Apache is helped by a varnish cache, while https handshake is made by pound.

The server hosts a mediawiki site; mediawiki is known to be quite resource hungry, but mediawiki is configure to use a memcached server, not only on varnish. Anyway, this site's traffic is quite low.

Another site is hosted, and it has many accesses, but its code is quite optimized.

My question is: why does the apache's processes number start growing? what could be the reason? is there any apache parameter which I could change? any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

apache's server-status shows something like this:

```
Current Time: Thursday, 22-Nov-2018 22:11:32 CET
Restart Time: Thursday, 22-Nov-2018 17:01:50 CET
Parent Server Config. Generation: 6
Parent Server MPM Generation: 5
Server uptime: 5 hours 9 minutes 42 seconds
Server load: 1.56 1.62 1.60
Total accesses: 290978 - Total Traffic: 13.0 GB
CPU Usage: u3035.84 s853.12 cu95.02 cs23.17 - 21.6% CPU load
15.7 requests/sec - 0.7 MB/second - 46.8 kB/request
211 requests currently being processed, 29 idle workers

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWK_WW_WWWWWWWWWW__WW_WWWWWW
_WWWW_WWWW__WWWW__WWWWWKWW_W__WW_WW_W____W_K____................
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv     PID         Acc         M   CPU      SS    Req    Conn  Child   Slot    Client  Protocol    VHost   Request
0-5     7078    39/1894/7033    W   51.62   2474    0   1212.2  76.84   291.35  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
1-5     7079    26/1754/6210    W   46.84   2617    0   325.6   69.37   232.28  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
2-5     6992    45/2272/7227    W   65.72   2063    0   967.3   135.68  323.88  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
3-5     7115    34/1956/6752    W   51.85   2276    0   550.6   75.82   255.04  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
4-5     7116    13/2177/7569    W   55.30   1474    0   95.5    97.34   363.31  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
5-5     24741   38/38/2319      W   0.81    2303    0   470.6   0.46    78.81   localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
6-5     7164    8/1820/3582     W   55.88   2273    0   2053.8  88.03   152.63  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /indice.php?id=95&includisottoaree=1&parole=dieci+comandame
7-5     6991    41/2284/4871    W   61.35   2411    0   1672.6  101.89  225.53  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /indice.php?id=151&area=video&includisottoaree=1&parole=die
8-5     7177    13/1905/5509    W   54.31   2513    0   110.7   65.53   242.78  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /indice.php?id=95&includisottoaree=1&parole=dieci+comandame
9-5     7178    19/1685/3773    W   57.13   2311    0   230.0   85.37   198.94  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
10-5    6993    10/1730/6138    W   58.98   2153    0   279.8   77.14   269.71  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /indice.php?id=95&includisottoaree=1&parole=dieci+comandame
11-5    7203    24/1800/7684    W   64.24   2497    0   410.8   94.65   378.47  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
12-5    24767   25/322/4734 W   8.75    1703    0   949.1   8.59    193.58  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
13-5    7274    26/2444/4303    W   62.34   1077    0   265.0   84.95   165.15  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
14-5    6994    27/1825/3191    W   51.14   2257    0   200.5   116.68  183.87  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
15-5    7275    11/1920/5549    W   47.93   2234    0   229.7   81.32   239.53  127.0.0.1   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
16-5    7296    38/1966/5571    W   54.47   2516    0   872.8   80.50   309.33  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
17-5    24768   12/28/1781  W   0.36    2249    0   135.1   0.22    67.21   localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
18-5    7351    10/2297/5512    W   75.49   1529    0   74.7    120.55  275.52  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
19-5    7352    13/2282/3062    W   65.76   2157    0   347.7   86.21   125.06  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
20-5    7381    23/2084/2791    W   57.86   2017    0   1473.5  180.55  242.64  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
21-5    7382    6/2094/4607 W   55.89   2571    0   33.0    78.08   188.96  127.0.0.1   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
22-5    7407    24/2039/4816    W   54.73   2393    0   518.9   81.25   208.01  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /indice.php?id=95&includisottoaree=1&parole=dieci+comandame
23-5    6990    6/1881/3829 W   52.14   2369    0   80.3    85.97   185.38  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
24-5    7408    41/2789/4877    W   81.54   1050    0   1052.5  139.01  231.51  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
25-5    7441    45/2442/4354    W   82.24   1014    0   4094.1  123.39  238.31  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
26-5    7442    9/1853/3907 W   40.79   2489    0   117.7   66.26   166.42  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
27-5    23874   4/1412/3792 W   34.98   2551    0   557.1   58.33   164.30  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
28-5    23926   3/1636/4245 W   49.36   2594    0   31.9    125.24  236.27  127.0.0.1   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
29-5    23927   47/2030/3795    W   58.84   1437    0   1151.4  95.04   168.33  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=19354&anchor=documento_6&rito
30-5    7477    33/2402/4309    W   62.78   2423    0   5086.6  146.04  252.14  localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=46711&anchor=documento_8&rito
31-5    24786   26/36/1660  W   1.07    2129    0   819.7   0.84    94.21   localhost   http/1.1    www.myserver.net:8080   GET /materiale/anteprima.php?file=35212&anchor=documento_7&rito
etc...
```

Why are most child still sending reply after a long time?

Does the high value of SS mean that the child servers are kept without reusing them and without killing them? `KeepAliveTimeout` is 5 sec....

Comment: Most apache installs default to the prefork mpm, switching to [any other](https://serverfault.com/q/383526/37681)  such as mpm_event with php-fpm will improve performance

Comment: Have you checked for Keepalives? If clients (this could be Varnish itself) are keeping the connections open and the default timeout on idle connections is sufficiently long enough you can exhaust the pool of workers.