# Apache prefork module. Processes not being forked under heavy load

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd, mpm-prefork

I have an apache prefork module http server running on linux machine. The machine has 8GB RAM. I have following in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      512
    MaxClients       512
    MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that no more child processes are getting forked after 256 and the requests are getting queued. I can see the number of child processes stuck at 256 under heavy load.

The average memory of a httpd process is aboout 3.69 MB.

Comment: When your site is that busy consider using a different MPM. See https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use

Answer (score 2):

In addition to increasing the `MaxClients` and `ServerLimit`  settings to 512 you also need to raise  `MaxRequestWorkers` to `512`.

Quoted from [the fine manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html):

> ...  Sites which need to serve more than 256 simultaneous requests may need to increase [`MaxRequestWorkers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) ...

And a little bit further:

> ## MaxRequestWorkers Directive
>
> **Description**:    Maximum number of connections that will be processed simultaneously
>   **Syntax:** `MaxRequestWorkers number`
>
> The`MaxRequestWorkers` directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts over the `MaxRequestWorkers` limit will normally be queued
>   ...
>   For **non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork)**, `MaxRequestWorkers` translates into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to serve requests. The **default value is 256**; to increase it, you must also raise [`ServerLimit`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit).

Comment: Tried increasing `MaxRequestWorkers`. Didn't work for me. Process count is still stuck at 256.