# Should I increase MaxSpareServer?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, http, httpd.conf

Recently we have surfered a 2 minutes downtime in one Apache Server 2.4.
There is not any significant error in error_log like "Max server Limit reached" and neither in acces_log.

Moreover, there is not a huge amount of client request in access_log, and neither bots requests.

This is the behaviour of server-status.

[image]

We can see, how Apache Idle Workers decrease to zero before increasing. Notice that nagios monitoring check this each 5 minutes, so we have to consider that there may be some delay and the data may not be 100% reliable.

Finally, this is our server worker configuration:

```
  <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers       13
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers   150
ServerLimit      1024
MaxClients       1024
MaxRequestWorkers 1024
MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

Should we consider to increase the "MaxSpareServers" despite this is an unrecommnended practice in Apache documentation?

Does anyone have any clues on some other issue that I am overlooking?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also consider not using pre-fork https://serverfault.com/q/383526/546643

Comment: You are right, though I really don`t know if there exists any application which needs prefork mode in the plattform.

Comment: If there is, you should get rid of that too.

Comment: What does your load average, memory usage, and page file look like during that time?

Comment: load average, memory usage, and page file? Nothing at all. We also are monitoring this and there is not any other issue related to this.